# How do I improve the quality of imported OBJ objects and what blender processes or skills do I need to learn to fix them?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, import, photogrammetry

I'm learning how to create 3D models with drones. I have tried importing a 3d model obj from WebODM into blender, however once imported it loses a lot of the detail and it looks a mess. I have two questions:

1. How can I improve the process of importing the model into blender? I basically exported the 3d object from WebODM then imported it directly into Blender, the picture below is the result.
2. Once imported into blender, are there any specific blender processes or skills I need to learn to improve the models? Is there a process that fixes the mesh post-importing that will bring back the detail you can see in WebODM?

I'm a relative beginner in Blender, I have an ok understanding of low-poly modelling and recently tried learning about baking textures, but apart from that I am very inexperienced in this.

Comparison between WebODM 3D view and the obj imported into Blender:
[image]

Comment: Your picture on the left looks like a colored point-cloud. WebODM gives you the option to export those as well as obj file format. It might be worthwhile to see if you can get the point-cloud into Blender and do the mesh conversion there? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/point_cloud.html

Comment: Thank you, I think you're right and it might work better if I can convert it to a mesh in Blender. Will try and report back here with the result

Comment: I highly recommend CloudCompare (free, opensource) software or MeshLab to reconstruct mesh from point cloud. Blender has very limited capabilities regarding Point Cloud treatment

Comment: I'm voting to leave this question open.  Currently there are some suggestions for other software, but I don't think this question is outside of this SE's purview.  It's possible or even likely that someone has a solution, and on the offchance such an answer exists I'd like to leave the question open so they can post it.